# Excel VBA: WorksheetChange, whenever cell changes it edits a CSV file

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm trying to make it so whenever a cell has changed within a certain range on my spreadsheet, it will trigger a script to edit the data in a csv file with the data from the range on the spreadsheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A1"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Call ExportWorksheetAndSaveAsCSV
    End If

End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub ExportWorksheetAndSaveAsCSV()

    Dim wbkExport As Workbook
    Dim shtToExport As Worksheet

    Set shtToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")     'Sheet to export as CSV
    Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
    shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:="/Users/samb/Desktop/test2.csv", FileFormat:=6
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    wbkExport.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

I put A1 just as a test but I haven't gotten as far as testing if the Worksheet_Change is functioning yet. I've tried running to ExportWorksheetAndSaveAsCSV subroutine manually and I returns

```
Run-time error 1004: Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed
```

I found this code online to assist me with editing CSV files, but can't seem to get it to work.

I should point out I'm using Excel for Mac in case it's relevant

Thanks for any help anyone can give!

EDIT:

I found this code online which seems to work but I'm trying to amend it to use it on a data range. Right now it specifies column 1, cell a etc. but I'm trying to tell it A5:F45 - any ideas?

```
Dim My_filenumber As Integer
Dim logSTR As String

My_filenumber = FreeFile

logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "A").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(2, "A").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(3, "A").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(4, "A").Value

Open "/Users/samb/Documents\test.csv" For Append As #My_filenumber
    Print #My_filenumber, logSTR
Close #My_filenumber
```

Comment: Based on your description, I suppose the error is raised in the line `wbkExport.SaveAs...`. For me the code works fine. Maybe check the provided directory (especially user name).

Comment: When this error occurs: Stop VBA and use the regular Excel Save As-functionality: Can you save the file with that specific name?

Comment: You need to include full path, not just directory (eg "C:/Users/samb/Desktop/test2.csv")

Comment: @AntiDrondert I'm on Mac, not PC so my file path doesn't include C:/, as far as I know it starts with Users and goes on from there. I've used a path in this format elsewhere in VBA and its worked

Comment: Just edited my original post with new code

Comment: **(a)** you shouldn't change the question you're asking. SO is not meant to answer a question to a user, but to a community. If you have a new question, ask a new question. **(b)** Don't mix "/" and "\" in a path. **(c)** Just use a `for`-loop to process all rows